# C# JSON deserialize

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I don't know how to deserialize this json string:

```
[ [ [ "JR10", "Test1", 142, 199, 66 ], [ "JR10", "Test2", 142, 199, 66 ] ] ]
```

into an array inside an array.

for example:
`messages[0]` would contain an array containing `"JR10", "Test1", 142, 199, 66`
`messages[0][0]` would contain the string `"JR10"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to deserialize this json string:

Normally when you want to deserialize a JSON string to an object you use a JSON serializer. For example using the build in [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
var json = "[ [ [ \"JR10\", \"Test1\", 142, 199, 66 ], [ \"JR10\", \"Test2\", 142, 199, 66 ] ] ]";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize<object[][][]>(json);
Console.WriteLine(result[0][0][0]); // "JR10"
Console.WriteLine(result[0][0][1]); // "Test1"
Console.WriteLine(result[0][1][0]); // "JR10"
Console.WriteLine(result[0][1][1]); // "Test2"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an object that can deal with serialising and desierialising:

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

Code similar to this should achieve what you want.

```
JSONSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

Array[][] anArray = JSONSerializer.Deserialize<Array[][]>(JSON);
```